# How to inserting data from install.xml file into mysql database in moodle

Tags: moodle

In moodle site (use moodle Version 2.6.3), I have generated install.xml file by XMLDB editor, but it's use only to create table in database during plugin installation. I want to insert some default rows in the table also.

Any body can help me how to edit in install.xml file for insert data

Answer (score 1):

To add data after an install, create a file called yourplugin/db/install.php with

UPDATE: added xml parser

```
defined('MOODLE_INTERNAL') || die;

require_once($CFG->libdir . '/xmlize.php');

function xmldb_yourpluginname_install() {
    global $CFG, $OUTPUT, $DB;
    // Your add data code here.
    $xmltext = file_get_contents('import.xml');
    $records = parse_xml($xmltext, 'records', 'record');
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $DB->insert_record('yourtablename', $record);
    }
}

/**
 * Converts XML text into an array of stdclass objects.
 *
 * @param type $text - xmltext
 * @param type $elementnames - plural name of elements
 * @param type $elementname - name of element
 * @return array|boolean - array of record objects
 */
function parse_xml($text, $elementnames, $elementname) {
    // Seems that xmlize needs a lot of memory.
    ini_set('memory_limit', '256M');

    // Ensure content is UTF-8.
    $content = xmlize($text, 1, 'UTF-8');

    $records = array();
    if (!empty($content[$elementnames]['#'][$elementname])) {
        $rows = $content[$elementnames]['#'][$elementname];
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            $fields = $row['#'];
            $row = new stdClass();
            foreach ($fields as $fieldname => $fieldvalue) {
                $row->$fieldname = $fieldvalue[0]['#'];
            }
            $records[] = $row;
        }
        return $records;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Russell England for giving suggestion
But, I want to insert data by install.xml file
Can I insert data by writing statements in install.xml file?

Comment: No. The Moodle mechanism for inserting data during install is via install.php. install.xml is only for the definition of the table structure.

Comment: As Davosmith says, install.xml is only used for creating the tables - I've updated the answer with an xml parser if you need to import data from an xml file.